# Was there a bracha on blowing the silver trumpet?

Tags: halacha, rosh-hashanah-new-year, rosh-chodesh-new-month, chagim-holidays, chatzotzerot-trumpets

The Torah mentions blowing the silver trumpet at various times during the year (e.g., RH, chagim).  Was there a bracha on blowing the silver trumpets?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I believe that most brachos are Rabbinical enactments. I have no idea when they were established, but if they were established after the trumpets stopped being used, it's likely that there was no blessing on blowing the trumpets.

Comment: Check seder hakorbanos